# How to get response headers of a failed fetch request in java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, fetch, next.js13

In my react application I'm doing a simple fetch inside my `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api-production.afghantell.com/apiv1/eligibilities",
    );
    console.log(res.status);
    console.log(res.headers);
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Everything is good when the response is successful. But I can't access `res` when the request fails for example with a 400 Error, Even using try catch blocks wasn't any help. There is a specific `X-reason` attribute in this failed fetch response that I need to access but I can't.

Comment: Fetch _doesn't_ error on non-2xx responses, so that seems unlikely.

Comment: The `aurelia-fetch-client` library is it completely framework agnostic and dependency free wrapper around the fetch function which handles all of this delightfully. I've used it with react before and you can use it with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make an http request inside a **useEffect**.
you have defined an asynchronous **fetchData()** function to perform the request. However, you are using await find() in your code.
is not the correct way to handle errors in an asynchronous request.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://api-production.afghantell.com/apiv1/elegibilidades");
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Error en la solicitud: " + res.status);
      }
      
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data.estado);
      console.log(res.headers);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error en la solicitud:", error);
      //Here you can access the "message" attribute of the error for specific details.
    }
  }

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

**fetch()** performs the request If the response is not successful (status code other than 200), it throws an error with details of the response status.
Then.
In the **catch** block, the **message** attribute of the error is accessed to get information about the error

Comment: The problem is that error object in catch block has no attribute that I can access. It's just a string